# iAd - not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, iad

I'm adding iAd on my app.... I managed to have the banner sliding from the bottom (just above my tab bar, 0, 410 i guess)... but only when i launch the app the first time. when then i try to switch the wifi off on my testing device to check if i get the blank banner i get the following message:ADBannerView: WARNING A banner view (0x1b11d0) has an ad but may be obscured. This message is only printed once per banner view. Can please somebody help me??

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    NSLog(@"there are ads to show");
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}
//----hide banner if can't load ad.
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{ 

if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    NSLog(@"sorry, no ads ");
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 410);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad]; 



aBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
aBanner.frame = CGRectOffset(aBanner.frame, 0, 410);
aBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
aBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[self.view addSubview:aBanner];



aBanner.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
[super viewDidLoad];
```

I know something is wrong in the CGRectOffset but I'm not able to figure it out.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIND THE PROBLEM.... WAS JUST A SIMPLE "!" HERE THE CODE FIXED:

```
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{

if (!self.bannerIsVisible) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    NSLog(@"there are ads to show");
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame,0, -banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
 }
    //----hide banner if can't load ad.
 -(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{ 

if (self.bannerIsVisible) { //THE PROBLEM WAS HERE!!!!
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animatedAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    NSLog(@"sorry, no ads ");
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad]; 



aBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
aBanner.frame = CGRectOffset(aBanner.frame, 0, 410);    
aBanner.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet   setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
aBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
[self.view addSubview:aBanner];



aBanner.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
[super viewDidLoad];
```